# I need to set two 2d Arrays equal to one another

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, return-value

Im trying to take a 2D array, which I return in one method, and call it into another method and set a second 2D array equal to the values of the first.

This is the first method:

```
int xx = 23;
int yy = 9;
move(xx,yy, myArray);
myNewArray = myArray;
first = false;
```

And the second:

```
    public static int[][] move(int x, int y, int[][] myNewArray)
 {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     String direction = input.next();
     boolean moving = true;
     while(moving == true)
     {
         if(direction.indexOf("up") >= 0)
         {
         myNewArray[x][y] = 0;
         myNewArray[x-1][y] = 5;
         moving = false;
         return myNewArray;
        }
        }
    }
```

Basically I'm trying to take a 2D array and make it into a map, in which you can move the character (the "5") throughout the map by changing the values of where the character is moving to, to 5, and where he is leaving  to 0.

Im trying to return an array in the 2nd method and then use it to replace the original array.

Comment: What is `myNewArray`? What is `xx`? What is `yy`? What is `myArray`? What values do these arrays hold?

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner at all of this. Thank you for your help. it was an honest lapse in coding ability (or lack there of).

Comment: For your question _I need to set two 2d Arrays equal to one another_ Just make a temp array and initialize it to `Array1`, then set `Array1 = Array2`, and set `Array2 = tempArray`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you want an actual copy of the contents then use `Arrays.copyOf()`:

What part of [`Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)) is not clear?

> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if
>   necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that
>   are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will
>   contain identical values. For any indices that are valid in the copy
>   but not the original, the copy will contain null. Such indices will
>   exist if and only if the specified length is greater than that of the
>   original array. The resulting array is of exactly the same class as
>   the original array.

#### If you just want another reference to the reference passed in:

```
newArray = oldArray;
```

but this has very little practical use

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that when you're executing `move(x,y,array)` you're not saving the returned result into another variable. As I think that the arrays are passed by value in Java, this method finnally does nothing.

Try this: `int[][] anotherArray = move(x, y, myArray)`

A non related issue, but you'll have to be careful with this function, because it will return an `ArrayOutOfBounds` or a `NullPointer Exception` if xx ==0